Disable geometry node for Shrinkwrap objects
I have a bottle and i put some drops of water on it with geometry node.

But when i want to use Shrinkwrap modifier for put stikers on bottle, geometry node affect on those too.
How can i fix this?

Use the little dots in the top right corner of the modifier to grab it and drag it above the drops one so it puts the stickers on first.

Spawn the bubbles in a separate object that uses "Object Info: Geometry" instead of "Group Input: Geometry"
